# how to filter products when button is clicked in React

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-redux, filtering, react-component

I have products fetched from API. And what I am trying to do is filter those products according to the button. So here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Product from "../components/sub-components/Product";
import LoadingBox from "../components/sub-components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/sub-components/MessageBox";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products } = productList;
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageCount, setpageCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts(currentPage));
    // dispatch(countProducts());
  }, [dispatch, currentPage]);

  const handlePageClick = (data) => {
    setCurrentPage(data.selected + 1);
    // scroll to the top
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  };

  const [ mugSelected, setMugSelected ] = useState(false);
  const [ shirtSelected, setShirtSelected ] = useState(false);

  const handleMugToggle = () => {
    setMugSelected(!mugSelected);
  };
  const handleShirtToggle = () => {
    setShirtSelected(!shirtSelected);
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h2 className="title">Products</h2>
          <div className="product-type-filter">
            <button className={mugSelected ? "clicked" : null} onClick={handleMugToggle}>Mug</button>
            <button className={shirtSelected ? "clicked" : null} onClick={handleShirtToggle}>Shirt</button>
          </div>
          <div className="products">
            <div className="row">
              <div>
                {loading ? (
                  <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
                ) : error ? (
                  <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
                ) : (
                  <div className="row center">
                    {products.map((product) => (
                      <Product key={product.added} product={product}></Product>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ReactPaginate
            previousLabel={"Prev"}
            nextLabel={"Next"}
            pageCount={40}
            marginPagesDisplayed={4}
            pageRangeDisplayed={1}
            onPageChange={handlePageClick}
            containerClassName={"pagination justify-content-center"}
            pageClassName={"page-item"}
            pageLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            previousClassName={"page-item"}
            previousLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            nextClassName={"page-item"}
            nextLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            breakClassName={"page-item"}
            breakLinkClassName={"page-link"}
            activeClassName={"active"}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So I have two buttons mug and shirt and when mug it clicked I want to show all the products whose 'type' is mug. Can you help me with this? I can share also my product action.
My data iscming like this from api:

```
{
    "tags": [
      "Trees"
    ],
    "price": 10.99,
    "name": "Handcrafted Trees Mug",
    "description": "enim corporis voluptatibus laudantium possimus alias dolorem voluptatem similique aut aliquam voluptatem voluptatem omnis id consequatur",
    "slug": "Handcrafted-Trees-Mug",
    "added": 1485723766805,
    "manufacturer": "OHara-Group",
    "itemType": "mug"
  },
  {
    "tags": [
      "Beach",
      "Ocean",
      "Water"
    ],
    "price": 19.99,
    "name": "Rustic Beach Mug",
    "description": "totam at veritatis eligendi assumenda ex quia praesentium quibusdam ducimus",
    "slug": "Rustic-Beach-Mug",
    "added": 1481573896833,
    "manufacturer": "Sipes-Inc",
    "itemType": "mug"
  },
```

So I dont have a lot of experience in React and especially in filtering, if you can help me I would be really glad.
Thanks...

Comment: kindly share what have you tried till now

Comment: Is your toggle logic working? eg When you toggle mug state, don't you need to toggle shirt state also? or is it ok for both mug and shirt to be selected simultaneously?

Comment: Yes my toggles are working and they works separately. So for example if both are selected, all the products need to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Add this effect to have filtered list on every render

```
 const [selectedProducts, setSelectedProducts] = useState([]);

   useEffect(()=>{
       const filteredList = products.filter(prod=> 
           mugSelected && prod.itemType=="mug" || 
           shirtSelected && prod.itemType=="shirt" );
       setSelectedProducts(filteredList);
   },[products, mugSelected, shirtSelected])
```

Then, in the render part

```
<div className="row center">
    {selectedProducts.map((product) => (
        <Product key={product.added} product={product}/>
    ))}
</div>
```